# State of a relation and instance of a relation

Tags: database, relational-database

how to tell if a relation state is an instance of the relation?

Given a relation schema VEHICLE (Vin#, Lic#, State, Model, Price, Reg_fee)

`F (fd1, fd2, fd3, fd4, fd5, fd6)`

`fd1: (Lic#, State) -> Vin#;`
`fd2: Vin# -> Lic#;`
`fd3: State -> Reg_fee;` 
`fd4: Vin# -> Model;`
`fd5: Vin# -> State;` 
`fd6: Model -> Price`

[image]

Given the relation state and functional dependencies, can you comment if the relation state is an instance of the relation schema?

Comment: Can you reword your question?  What exactly are you looking for in the result set?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sample data. If the sample data fulfills all the functional dependencies, then that state is an instance of the relation. If it doesn't, it's not.

In real-world database design, functional dependencies are expected to hold for all real data, not just for sample data. Model determines price in the sample data, but not in the real world.